# Home Dash/Side Bar hide when mouse is over them. In Menu Bar, Shutdown not working. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, shutdown, unity-dash, home-directory

I've installed a weekly update from Ubuntu (Canonical) and when I reboot the System (and whenever I have to login to the PC), I face the following problems:

- The Home Dash bottom is not working;
- When the mouse pointer is over the Home Dash bottom or the Side Bar bottoms, they hide and come back again a few seconds after. The same with opened application windows (The Side Bar is configured as fixed on the left side of the Screen):
- In the Menu Bar the Shutdown command doesn't work.

Errors reported by the system:

2018-01-13 17:01    2018-01-13 17:01 UTC    Crash   compiz-core

2018-01-12 12:01    2018-01-12 12:01 UTC    Crash   /usr/bin/compiz

Additional data:

- System: ThinkPad T400
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Please, can you help to solve these problems?
If you need any additional information or data, please, let me know.
Thank you.
Best regards,

Artur Campos

Comment: 1) Don't show your email address like this. 2) Did you got an ubuntu update recently ?

Comment: Removed email address from question.  Answers to questions need to go on this site, so others can benefit.